# draw triangle shaped program in python

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

This is the question i am working on, its a python [Website](http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/7c-loops/):

> Modify the previous program in two ways. First, instead of a square,
>   make it draw a triangle shaped like this: `◤`. Second, instead of
>   always having 5 lines, it should take the desired size as input from
>   `input()`. For example, if the input is 3, then the output should be
>
> ```
> 111
> 11
> 1
> ```

I have solved this so far, it has a predefined `input()` as told in the question.
my solving so far:

```
n=int(input())
for i in range(0, 3):
  X = 0-1
  for j in range(0, 3-i):
    X = (X*10)+1
  print(X)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what your question is. If you're asking how to do it n times. then `range(0, n)` or `range(n)` will do that (If you are starting from 0 then you can omit the 0 from range.

```
n=int(input())
for i in range(n):
    X = 1
    for j in range(n-1-i): # -1 to reduce by factor of 10
        X = (X*10)+1
    print(X)
```